# Drop Down Search Field in Django

Tags: python, django, search, dropdown

Does anyone know of some way to create a text box in Django where when you begin typing in the box, suggestions that contain those letters from a list begin to appear underneath the text box? Similar to Google's autocomplete.

For example in a box where I type in "Br" results underneath the text box may be 
"Bread", "Bran", "Abraision"

Answer (score 3):

django-autocomplete-light is all what you want .Please go through their tutorial[django-autocomplete-light](https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/)

Answer (score 0):

You need jquery autocomplete plugins. With help of this plugins you send post requests to your django whenever user types something in the input field. You can write return data in special window below input field. For example check this link: https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/